# Two textview results in one activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

i am developing an android application in which 5 calculations are there according to the input of user... and these 5 calculations result has to be displayed through textviews in another activity... I did half code.. in which one result is diplayed in the second activity by textview but i am in confusion about how to do the other 4 calculations throufgh other textviews...

```
public void sum(View v)
    {
        long sum1=0;
        EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
        EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText2);
        EditText et3 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText3);
        EditText et4 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText4);



        sum1=getSum(et1.getText().toString() + et2.getText().toString() + et3.getText().toString() + et4.getText().toString());

startActivity(new Intent(this, result.class).putExtra("name", sum1 + "")); 

    }

public long getSum(String text) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        long sum1 = 0;
        char[] name = new char[text.length()];
        name = text.toCharArray();


        for(int i=0; i<text.length(); i++)
        {
            sum1 += value( name[i] );

        }
        while (sum1>9)
        {
            sum1 = findDigitSum(sum1);
        }

        return sum1;
    }





    public long findDigitSum(long n) 
    {
        int sum1 = 0;
        while (n != 0) 
        {
            sum1 += n % 10;
            n = n / 10;
        }
        return sum1;
    }



    private int value(char a) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(a) {
        case 'A': 
           return 1;
        case 'B':
           return 2;
        case 'C':
           return 3;
        case 'D': 
            return 4;
         case 'E':
            return 5;
         case 'F':
            return 6; 
         case 'G': 
             return 7;
          case 'H':
             return 8;
          case 'I':
             return 9;
          case 'J': 
              return 1;
          case 'K':
              return 2;
           case 'L':
              return 3;
           case 'M': 
               return 4;
            case 'N':
               return 5;
            case 'O':
               return 6; 
            case 'P': 
                return 7;
             case 'Q':
                return 8;
             case 'R':
                return 9;
             case 'S': 
                 return 1;
             case 'T':
                 return 2;
              case 'U':
                 return 3;
              case 'V': 
                  return 4;
               case 'W':
                  return 5;
               case 'X':
                  return 6; 
               case 'Y': 
                   return 7;
                case 'Z':
                   return 8;
                 default:
            return 0;
    }
    }
```

Second Activity

result.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.result_xm);
    TextView txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView21);
    txt2.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("name"));
   }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are asking, do you want to know how to pass the values you calculate to the 2nd screen, or how to actually calculate them? If you want to pass more than 1 value to the 2nd `Activity`, just add them to the `Bundle` with `.putExtra("calc2", "calc 2 values")` and pull them out with `.getStringExtra("calc2")`...

Comment: ya...exaxtly ... in the above code i pass one calculation... next I need to calculate in a different way and display it in the second screen in another textview....

Comment: .putExtra("name", sum1 + ""));.... here in this code I already passed one result... i need to pass another result to the activity... where  I have to add that one for example name1 and sum2 ... how i will add it to the bundle.. pls help me...

Comment: You can pass an many extras as you want to the `Bundle`. @codeMagic beat me at writing the answer, but his answer should show you what you need.

Comment: thanks for all ... as i am very slow in this code writing... pls wait 4 some time.. I will accept the answer... once I finished it... once again .. thanks 4 all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm in confusion on exactly what you are doing but you can pass more than one `extra` at a time`. If possible, do all of your calculations in`sum(View v)`then pass them all. So change your`Intent` to something like

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, result.class)
i.putExtra("sum1", sum1 + "");
i.putExtra("sum2". String.valueOf(sum2));
// etc
startActivity(i);
```

then get them in your next `Activity` with something like

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.result_xm);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String sum1 = i.getStringExtra("sum1");
    String sum2 = i.getStringExtra("sum2");
    // etc
```

Comment: Ok, hope it works for you. `Bundles`, as suggested by others, are fine too but I usually only use them if I will be passing data from one `Activity` through multiple others but that is up to you.

Comment: @ Code magic... thanks.. i think this will work.. i am checking with this code...thanks a lot..4 ur help ....

Comment: You're welcome. I will also suggest that you may want to think about error checking in case the user inputs an invalid character and check that `getIntent()` isn't `null` if you can get to that `Activity` from others

Comment: thanks Codemagic .. I checked it worked for the 2 nd textview.... thanks a lot...and I accepted your answer...and special thanks to Steven Byle and Chris K

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bundle to pass arguments to your activity:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

bundle.putString("arg1", argument to pass);
bundle.putString("arg2", argument to pass);
bundle.putString("arg3", argument to pass);
bundle.putString("arg4", argument to pass);

intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: thanks Chris... for u r help ... let me check with the code.. and if any help needed 4 me.. pls help... once again thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You can put any number of extras in your intent, name it differently and use that name to recognize that piece of data in the receiving activity.